# Avro Schema Generation - Object Reordering

Tags: avro, jackson-dataformat-avro

I need to generate an AVRO schema from an existing Java Model. I then want to use that schema to generate Java objects so I can replace my existing model with the generated one, making the schema the source of truth.

I am having a problem which I will try to illustrate with this example.

I have a basic Java class:

```
public class Car {

private String price;
private String engine;

public Car(String price, String engine) {
    this.price = price;
    this.engine = engine;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getEngine() {
    return engine;
}

public void setEngine(String engine) {
    this.engine = engine;
}
}
```

I want to generate an avro schema which represents this class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException {
    System.out.println(generateAvroSchema());
}

public static String generateAvroSchema() throws JsonMappingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new AvroFactory());
    AvroSchemaGenerator gen = new AvroSchemaGenerator();
    mapper.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(Car.class, gen);
    Schema schema = gen.getGeneratedSchema().getAvroSchema();
    return schema.toString(true);
}
```

The result of this is:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Car",
  "namespace" : "app",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "engine",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "price",
    "type" : [ "null", "string" ]
  } ]
}
```

When the schema is generated the object attributes are ordered alphabetically. If I was to use this schema to generate a new java model, the constructor argument ordering would be different from the source.

My question is, is there any configuration I can use when generating the schema to preserve attribute ordering and not default to alphabetical?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue as well, solved following https://github.com/fasterxml/jackson-dataformat-csv/issues/40

Basically calling `mapper.disable(MapperFeature.SORT_PROPERTIES_ALPHABETICALLY);` on the mapper.

Comment: This seems to be deprecated. Can you share how to do it?